# Earth Engine Plugin in QGIS to use existing vector

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, google-earth-engine, vector

I success to run this script in Earth Engine Code Editor (with Java). My vector shape is shareable to you.

```
var pemotong = ee.FeatureCollection("users/muhammadichsan/mencoba_clip");
var dataset = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003');
var elevation = dataset.select('elevation');
var slope = ee.Terrain.slope(elevation);
Map.setCenter(108.5550607304925137, -6.4026603600933889);
Map.addLayer(slope, {min: 0, max: 255}, 'slope');
Map.addLayer(slope.clip(pemotong));
```

Now, I have QGIS and EarthEnginePlugin with Python API. I want to do same to QGIS. So, I write this in built in python editor in QGIS

```
import json
import ee
from ee_plugin import Map

pemotong = ee.FeatureCollection("????")

dataset = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003')
elevation = dataset.select('elevation')
slope = ee.Terrain.slope(elevation)
Map.setCenter(108.5550607304925137, -8.2129304795692413, 10)
Map.addLayer(slope.clip(pemotong))
```

So the question is, what is "????" if I want use existing vector layer in QGIS?.
For example, I have active layer named 'xyz'

What I have done, but still error

```
import ee
from ee_plugin import Map

xyz = iface.activeLayer()
pemotong = ee.FeatureCollection(xyz)

dataset = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003')
elevation = dataset.select('elevation')
slope = ee.Terrain.slope(elevation)
Map.setCenter(108.5550607304925137, -8.2129304795692413, 10)
Map.addLayer(slope.clip(pemotong))
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this QGIS plugin, but in Earth Engine, in order to use a feature collection you must either

- [upload it to become an Earth Engine asset](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/importing), or
- *if it is very small*, you could write it out in code (i.e. take your QGIS data and turn it into `ee.Feature`s using Python code that iterates over the collection in QGIS). The disadvantage of this approach is that it means your dataset is being uploaded anew with each individual request (each time you run `addLayer`).

If [this is the site](https://gee-community.github.io/qgis-earthengine-plugin/) for the plugin then I don't see any mention of relevant features provided by the plugin.

Comment: ((ee.Feature using python code that iterates over the collection in QGIS)). Would you explain that code or any reference?

Comment: @Ichsan I'm sorry, but I am not familiar with QGIS and so cannot write an example.